# How to omit empty part-000x files from Python streaming MapReduce job

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I created a Python mapper that I run as a Hadoop streaming MapReduce job. It validates the input and writes a message to output if the input is invalid.

```
...
# input from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    indata = json.loads(line)
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(indata,schema)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError, error:
        # validation against schema failed
        print error.message
    except:
        # other exceptions
        raise
```

My question: The mapper writes the message for invalid input as expected, but it also creates empty "part-0000x" files for valid input.

I would like to omit the empty output files. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To omit the empty output files use `LazyOutputFormat`class. It generates part files only when at least one record is generated for the particular file.

But `LazyOutputFormat` is in Java API, you find the corresponding API for Python

Comment: Thank you this is correct. Since I use Hadoop Streaming I can pass in the parameter "-lazyOutput" to the Streaming job despite using Python for the logic.